# Property '0' does not exist on type 'number | [number, number]'

Tags: typescript

I have a component called A and this component has an interface, like below

```ts
interface A1 {
    isSingle: true;
    value: number;
}

interface A2 {
    isSingle: false;
    value: [number, number];
}

export type IA = A1 | A2;

function A({ isSingle = false, value }: IA): void {
    if (!isSingle) {
        console.log(value[0]);
    }
};

export default A;
```

As it shows if we pass `isSingle=false` we must expect the value as a tuple with two number elements. But when I logged `value[0]` I got this TypeScript error:

```
 Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'number | [number, number]'.   Property '0' does not exist on type 'number | [number, number]'.
```

I can't figure out how I can solve that.

Comment: Destructuring breaks the compiler's ability to associate the check on `isSingle` with the type of `value` (see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), it works if you don't: https://tsplay.dev/Nnl1BW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the default function parameter set on `isSingle`. This breaks TypeScript's type inference and according to your interface definitions, `isSingle` should always be defined.

```
interface A1 {
    isSingle: true;
    value: number;
}

interface A2 {
    isSingle: false;
    value: [number, number];
}

export type IA = A1 | A2;

function A({ isSingle, value }: IA): void {
    if (!isSingle) {
        console.log(value[0]);
    }
};

export default A;
```

Answer (score 0):

type IA is the union of two different types `A1` and `A2`, so the compiler doesn't know at compile time whether the value is an array or a number. you sholud narrow down the type of value to `numbers` or `[number, number]` before use.

**Example**

```js
interface A1 {
    isSingle: true;
    value: number;
}

interface A2 {
    isSingle: false;
    value: [number, number];
}

export type IA = A1 | A2;

// using type guard
const isA2 = (a: IA): a is A2 => !a.isSingle;

function A({ isSingle = false, value }: IA): void {
  if (!isSingle && isA2({ isSingle, value })) {
    console.log(value[0]);
  } else {
    console.log(value);
  }
};
```